# apache rewrite index.php with trailing /

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I had a wordpress site installed on one of my domains. I decided to delete it and create a new custom site.

However in my logs I see visits to old wordpress site urls, that no longer exist.

the visits are to pages similar two the following

http://betbusters.net/index.php/blog
(notice the trailing slash after index.php)

These pages do not give a 404, as the index.php page exists.
However the trailing / after index.php gives very strange results to the page.

Is there a way to rewrite index.php/title/title2 to plain index.php     ?
(Please note that I will be using links like index.php?variable=5&something=10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as very first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: In order for this to work I had to add RewriteEngine on to the .htaccess file. Thank you